# VBA SQL Server Query Connecting but not Returning Records

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I have this VBA code that issues a SQL Server query after a successful connection but the query returns no records (e.g., -1)

```
Function invested_funds() As Integer
Dim c As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim connectionstring As String
Dim sql As String

connectionstring = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=DESKTOP-2TTG3GQ\SQLEXPRESS;" & _
                   "Initial Catalog=DB;" & _
                   "Integrated Security=SSPI;"

Set c = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
c.Open connectionstring

sql = "select [DB].[dbo].[db].[CSRoot] " & _  
      "from [DB].[dbo].[db] " 

If c.State = adStateOpen Then
    Debug.Print ("Connected") 'This prints!
End If

Set rs = c.Execute(sql) 
Debug.Print (rs.RecordCount)
invested_funds = CInt(rs.RecordCount)

End Function
```

However, I know records exist and the exact same query in SSMS does indeed return records

```
select  [DB].[dbo].[db].[CSRoot]
from [DB].[dbo].[db]
```

Many records, in fact.

How can this be?

Comment: Don't rely on `RecordCount`. Try iterating through record set.

Comment: `select [DB].[dbo].[db].[CSRoot] from [DB].[dbo].[db]` is not the same query as `select CSRoot from [DB].[dbo].[db]`. The first query is not even valid t-sql syntax.  Change your VBA code to use the second query

Comment: @squillman you're right. That was a typo on my part. Edited. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I think you edited the wrong part of your question.

Comment: @Parfait you were absolutely right! `RecordCount` says -1 yet when I iterate through the set I see my records. Is it common knowledge that `RecordCount` is unreliable? Feel free to turn your comment into a question for credit.

Comment: If you do a `MoveLast` and then a `MoveFirst` you can typically get a reliable count.  When the cursor first opens it's positioned on the first record (assuming you got some hits from your SQL) - until you fetch all the records using `MoveLast` or by looping to `rs.EOF` you'll not know how many there are.  It's possible the database has sent you the first records before it has completed the query.

Comment: @TimWilliams thanks for this bit of knowledge. I had no idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the number of records using the rs.getRows function.

```
Function invested_funds() As Integer
    Dim c As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim connectionstring As String
    Dim sql As String
    
    connectionstring = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=DESKTOP-2TTG3GQ\SQLEXPRESS;" & _
                       "Initial Catalog=DB;" & _
                       "Integrated Security=SSPI;"
    
    Set c = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    c.Open connectionstring
    
    sql = "select [DB].[dbo].[db].[CSRoot] " & _
          "from [DB].[dbo].[db] "
    
    If c.State = adStateOpen Then
        Debug.Print ("Connected") 'This prints!
    End If
    
    Set rs = c.Execute(sql)
    
    Dim arr As Variant, n As Integer
    
    arr = rs.GetRows
    n = UBound(arr, 2) + 1
    'Debug.Print (rs.RecordCount)
    Debug.Print n
    invested_funds = n

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

A `RecordCount` of -1 does **not** mean that your query did not return any records ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/recordcount-property-ado?view=sql-server-ver16)):

> The property returns -1 when ADO cannot determine the number of records or if the provider or cursor type does not support RecordCount.
>
> [...]
>
> The cursor type of the Recordset object affects whether the number of records can be determined. **The RecordCount property will return -1 for a forward-only cursor**; the actual count for a static or keyset cursor; and either -1 or the actual count for a dynamic cursor, depending on the data source.

The default value of `CursorType` is `adOpenForwardOnly`, so this behavior is expected. To get an actual count, use a `CursorType` of `adOpenStatic` or `adOpenKeyset` instead.