# VB6: ADODB.RecordSet.Open Fails without DoEvents

Tags: vb6, adodb

I have to fix something in some old VB6-lagacy code and found the following:

```
Public Function openRec(db As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset, sql As String) As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    rs.CacheSize = 8000
    rs.Open sql, db, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockOptimistic
    DoEvents

    openRec = Err.Number
End Function
```

And the calling  function looks something like this:

```
Public Function ShowDataGrid(sql As String)
    If openRec(DataDb, rs, sql) = 0 Then
        'WriteLog("Found Records: " & rs.RecordCount)
        If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
            Do Until rs.EOF
                ' Do something with each record
                rs.MoveNext
                DoEvents
            Loop
        End IF
    End If
End Function
```

The function `openRec` just opens a recordset which the caller iterates through.
However, I was wonderiung about the `DoEvents` and when I comment it out, the function breaks on only one sql-statement, all others are working fine.
It is a statement, returning about 380k Recordsets from a SQL-Server-database:

```
SELECT * FROM PRO_TEIL_AUFTRAG WHERE TETEILNR LIKE '%%' AND  PAAUFTRAG = 0 AND MEMERKMAL = 1 ORDER BY TETEILNR
```

If `DoEvents` is present everything works fine but if I remove it, the function fails with

```
Err.Number: -2147217915, 
Err.Description: Das Objekt war geöffnet (something like "object was already opened")
```

Any ideas why this is and how work around with it?

I cannot really debug it since its running on a productionmachine without IDE. I only can use `WriteLog`-Statements.
On the dev-machine I use a small Access-Database returning just one record which will work in any case.

Additional Problem:
In the calling code when I uncomment the `WriteLog`-Statment, I get an Error when I try to access `rs.RecordCount`:

```
Err: -2147024882
Description: Nicht genügend Arbeitsspeicher ("out of memory")
```

I don't have any clue if its some weired VB6-Stuff, if it depends on the OS (dev: win xp, prod: win7-64), the Database (dev: access, prod: sql server), the number of records returned (dev: 1, prod: 380k) or anything else

Comment: That would be a fine example of very bad code, where errors are first created due to complete misunderstanding of data flows and then suppressed with `On Error Resume Next` and `DoEvents`. Remove `On Error Resume Next` and `DoEvents` from `openRec` and add a test for `rs.State` as the first thing (at least dump that to log).

Comment: Of course it's bad code, thats not the question. The creator has retired and I have to maintain it somehow... I already tried logging and checking the state. Before .open its always adStateClosed (0) and after .open its adStateOpen (1). The caller correctly closes the Recordset after using it

Comment: Exactly where does the error happen then? I thought it was on `Open`? Does the query produce warnings (they are returned as a separate recordset), does `rs.NextRecordset` return anything? And how does this code work at all I wonder, given that `adOpenForwardOnly` [will result](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76325175/11683) in `-1` RecordCount, so the `If` will never be entered?

Comment: openRec produces the error at .open. But just when using SQL-Server. The same Database exported to Access does not. Even with SQL-Server it produces the error at only this statement (which yields 380k records), all others work. If DoEvents is called afterwards Err.Numer is set to 0. I don't know if DoEvents changes the Err-Object? And IF openRec produces the error and I just ignore it (return 0) the calling function works without any problem and can iterate through the recordsets

Answer (score -1):

First off, I'd optimize the SQL statement by swapping WHERE conditions around:

```
WHERE PAAUFTRAG = 0 AND MEMERKMAL = 1 AND TETEILNR LIKE '%%'
```

Put the faster numeric conditions at the front, which reduces the result size that the subsequent conditions have to work on, leaving the slowest condition (string and LIKE) for the remaining records.

Instead of `rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient` try `rs.CursorLocation = adUseServer`.

You'll lose the .RecordCount property of the recordset that way, but that can be circumvented, e.g.

```
Public Function ShowDataGrid(sql As String)
    If openRec(DataDb, rs, sql) = 0 Then
        If NOT (rs.BOF AND rs.EOF) Then
            Do Until rs.EOF
                ' Do something with each record
                rs.MoveNext
                ' DoEvents
            Loop
        End IF
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: thanks. that will for sure speed up execution but it does not answer my initial question about the DoEvents-Line

Comment: It _may_ be related to the CursorLocation, as with the original code the _client_ has to handle the Recordset cursor instead of the server (```adUseServer```, which is the default if omitted). It _may_ also be the reason why you get the Out of memory error. I'm guessing here, but the DoEvents might give the OS enough time to swap out memory as needed, hence the application works as expected. But that only cures the symptom, not the cause. See [this discussion](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?798773-adUseClient-vs-adUseServer) on adUseClient vs. adUseServer.

Comment: The order of the expressions in the `WHERE` clause [does not matter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3152225/11683). The rest seems irrelevant, as it's `openRec` that needs fixing, not `ShowDataGrid`.